# Best way to provide `delta` of changes in database record

Tags: caching, synchronization, versioning, delta

We have a REST API which is used by a mobile application. As a distilled version, let's assume the API provides list of books and their contents such as author's name, publisher, year and content of pages.

The mobile app needs to cache the last 10 books in local storage so it always has 10 books available offline. The books might be updated at the server and the app must sync with the latest changes.

- A new book is added
- A books is updated
- A book is deleted
- etc

We need a way, at the server, to only provide the changes that have been made since the last time mobile was synced. So instead of requesting the whole latest 10 books they only request what has changed since the last fetch.

This is something that has been implemented in version management systems like Git but we are looking for a very simple way to do it with database records.

What is a very very very simple way to implement such `delta`?

Comment: comparing timestamps? but that will require you to push an entire db entry and not just the changes in that entry.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. You just need to store the UTC date-time each book was created/modified in your database, and similarly in the app. The app also needs to store the last date-time it requested an update of book information.

Then when your app requests a book list, it can provide the 'last check' UTC date-time to the API, and the API can respond with only books which have changed since that time - added, modified, and deleted. So you need to transfer deleted books too - with a flag to indicate it's been deleted. Probably also transmit a count of the number of books which should be in the list so that your app can verify it's got the correct count.